# How to handle toad invalid pointer operation?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I get this error : toad invalid pointer operation , when I want to import data from excel.

```
Toad version   : 12.1

Oracle version :Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

I ve restarted TOAD , even Computer but it does not work.

thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know TOAD is not open-source so if you've found a bug you cannot fix it yourself; you'll have to report it.

Comment: thanks, but ı worry about this error maybe can occur because of wrong paramaters (maybe memory settings?)

Comment: Doing a quick google throws up https://support.software.dell.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/52537 and https://support.software.dell.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/48991. Do the solutions to either of those help you?

Comment: they are not working

Comment: Go to Dell support or the Toad World forums. Your error is accompanied by an error log that includes the call stack that is helpful. If you provide that to Dell you'll get help. The forums are going to be the fastest route to resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and this was my solution (idea from https://support.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/52537):

To quickly remove any hidden formulas in the spreadsheet, I copied all the range of cells with the required data and pasted it into another spreadsheet.

On the following import operation everything worked smoothly.